# How to use nom take_while and is_digit for a &str input

Tags: rust, nom

I'm trying to learn nom and have a problem where `take_while` does not accept `is_digit` or any other `is_xxxx`.

I have rows that I want to parse that looks like this

```
#123 = ABCDEF (...);
```

where I want to get the '123' part (and eventually the ABCDEF and the (...) parts as well. But one thing at the time I guess).

My parser currently looks like this

```
use nom::{
  bytes::complete::take_while,
  character::is_digit,
  error::ParseError,
  IResult
};

// Get row id
fn id<'a, E: ParseError<&'a str>>(i: &'a str) -> IResult<&'a str, &'a str, E> {
    take_while(is_digit)(i)
}
```

The `is_digit` definition looks like this

```
pub fn is_digit(chr: u8) -> bool
```

And since the `id` parser takes a `&str` it will complain about the mismatch in types. But is it possible somehow to use the is_digit anyway? Can I do a type conversion somewhere without having to allocate anything. I really want this to be as efficient as possible.

It feels like the provided `is_xxxx` functions should be used in these kinds of situations, but I might be wrong about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily adapt `is_digit` to a `char`. First, all digits are valid ASCII, so we should check first if the character is ASCII. If it's ASCII, we can safely convert to `u8`.

```
// pub fn is_digit(chr: u8) -> bool;

pub fn is_char_digit(chr: char) -> bool {
    return chr.is_ascii() && is_digit(chr as u8)
}
```

You could also use the trait method [is_dec_digit](https://docs.rs/nom/4.0.0/nom/trait.AsChar.html#tymethod.is_dec_digit), which is just a wrapper for [char.is_digit](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_digit).

Comment: That looks like a nifty technique. Does it have any perfomance implications?

Comment: Not particularly, as long as you inline it. If you want it to be faster, you can directly compare using `char.is_digit`, which should be slightly faster (or `is_dec_digit`, since it means fewer comparisons. In fact, this pretty much how nom does it (using is_dec_digit):
https://docs.rs/nom/4.0.0/src/nom/nom.rs.html#216

Answer (score 5):

I know it doesn't directly answer your question because it doesn't directly use `take_while` but you could use the `digit1` parser in `character::complete::digit1`.

It takes an `&str` and consumes 1 or more digits in [0..9] and returns an `&str`

Comment: Thanks! Not answering my question as you say, but definitely the correct way to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

Up-to-date solution using nom's [AsChar trait](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/trait.AsChar.html):

```
take_while1(AsChar::is_dec_digit)(input)
```